# What kind of bush is this?

Tags: identification, trees, flowers

I was walking around town with my kids the other day and this bush caught my eye. I just love it and want one of my own lol. Can someone help me out in identifying it please. It's located in north eastern North Dakota.

[image: flowerbush]

Answer (score 2):

Well it looks like a double flowered blossom, so its probably a Prunus variety, but as to whether its a Japanese flowering cherry such as Prunus Kanzan, or Prunus triloba, flowering almond, is hard to say, need sight of the trunk, overall growth habit and close up of the leaves.

UPDATED ANSWER

I would just offer a piece of advice though- there are myriads of Prunus flowering blossom trees, many with double flowers, and all vary enormously in size and growth habit, so your choice of blossom tree should be based on where you're going to plant it, so that you know it's not going to get too tall or wide for where it is, as much as what the blossom looks like. Regarding blossom, bear in mind its only there for a couple of weeks, in a windy year it'll be ripped off the tree quicker, and then you're looking at just the leaves for six months, so choice should also be related to overall appearance *without* the blossom present. And be prepared for the piles of browning blossom petals on the ground as the blooms fade!

Comment: Okay, I'll try and get those pictures today when we go for a walk :)

Comment: See updated answer...

Comment: When they are in bloom they are spectacular and  the right size for a smaller garden.  Out of bloom they are insignificant, flop around and don't even have any fall colour.  They stems get an infection and ooze a viscous sap.  When you cut them back they sucker.  Not on my list of favourites.

Comment: @kevinsky you could probably tell they're not on my favourite list either, although serried ranks of them in parks are stunning in spring.  I'd surface rooting as another problem with these, and the suckers they produce as they age. I'd always go for Prunus cistena or cerasifera, at least the leaves are a great colour, if I had to choose one.